# Error: the operation failed - 800401f3 - controlling out of office from vbscript

Tags: vbscript, outlook-2003

I wrote a vbscript to be able to control Out-Of-Office (OOO) for somebody else.  We are both in the same company, the same network.  The code works flawlessly on my PC but on his it pops that error message:

[image: error message]

Here is the first lines of my code including the 44th (like in the error message):

```
Sub olOutOfOffice(ActivateOOO)

    Dim olApp
    Set olApp = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olNameSpace
    Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim olFolder
    Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

    Dim olSession
    Set olSession = olApp.CreateObject("MAPI.Session") 'Line #44

    olSession.Logon "", "", False, False
```

Note that even though I do not use `olNameSpace` and `olFolder` in the rest of my script these lines `Set olNameSpace...` and `Set olFolder...` were necessary for that script to work on my PC.  However, on my colleague's PC, removing those lines from the code pop the same error as when they are present.

Comment: Pure Voodoo, but I'd ponder whether `olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6)` (mark the smelly 6) makes sense on your colleague's PC.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner; On my colleague's PC, when I add the line `olFolder.Display` right after `Set olFolder...` Outlook pops up like it should showing the inbox.

Comment: Ignore if you don't need further Voodoo, otherwise: 32 vs 64 bit (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikas/archive/2008/09/11/error-activex-component-can-t-create-object-mapi-session-on-vista.aspx); wrong object (olApp) for .CreateObject (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/74fdd007-1e04-493e-ac94-09364619de0d/outlook-2010-mapi-error?forum=ITCG)

Comment: Thanks but I have already came across these two websites.  What bugged me was that I was suppose to have the same installation as my colleague so I was sure it was not that.  Now it is confirmed, he does not have CDO 1.21 installed.  It probably will solve the problem (hopefully).  I will come back to update my post after I tested it.

Comment: It worked!!  It just confirms again that you should never assume anything when you code for someone else's PC :)  Thanks @Ekkehard.Horner for the support.  I will post an answer on how to activate the CDO 1.21 library for Outlook 2003.

Comment: In fact, just go to **[This site](http://www.ctimls.com/Support/KB/Error%20Fixes/Fix_CDO_Email_Error.htm#Outlook_2002_or_2003)**.  You basically just have to modify your installation of Office adding "Collaboration Data Objects" located under the "Microsoft Office Outlook" node (see **[this screenshot](http://www.ctimls.com/Support/Images/NonCTI%20Images/Office2003CDO.gif)**).